# Can I turn off display on my macbook when I'm using extended display, without closing the lid?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

I'm using MacBook's keyboard to work on it, but I'm also using the extended display for work. I'd like to turn off the MacBook's screen without closing the lid while using the external display.

My searches so far have revealed that this is not supported (unless I mess with some terminal commands, which I don't want to as I'm a relative newbie with Macs), but I'm wondering if I may have missed some source? Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1):

A hacky and simple way to achieve this: 1. Turn on "Mirror Displays" in display settings and 2. Turn down the brightness on your laptop all the way down to zero.

Comment: I did that yeah. But I don’t think that turns off the lcd panel, just brightness. I’m a bit perfectionist here looking for better solution, but if there’s no better one I’ll go with this.